# Breaking RSA given we know minimal solution to discrete log mod N

Tags: math, rsa, public-key-encryption, modular-arithmetic

So I'm trying to figure out the connection between the discrete log problem and RSA. I think this is what the following question is trying to do.

```
Suppose you have an oracle which gives you the smallest positive x satisfying
the following congruence:
                                  g^x ≡ k (mod N) 
where N = p*q for some distinct primes p and q, and g and k are any integers.
We also have one more condition that (p -1)/2 and (q -1)/2 are both primes.

What is the quickest way to find p and q? i.e. factor N.
```

So I'm completely lost on how to approach the solution to this problem. If somebody can provide me with hints/solution to solve this problem I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should try [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Crypto Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `g^x = 1`, the solution `x` will always be a divider of `(p-1)*(q-1)`. Choose some different g values, and you will likely find most factors of `(p-1)*(q-1)`. And as `(p-1)(q-1) = N - p - q + 1`, knowing `(p-1)(q-1)` and `N` results in knowing `p + q`. Knowing `N = p*q` and `p+q` is like knowing circumference and area of a rectangle, and can be quickly solved for `p` and `q`.